# What is the behaviour of FlagsAttribute Enum in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have the following code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [FlagsAttribute]
        private enum RenderType
        {
            DataUri = 0,
            GZip = 1,
            ContentPage = 2,
            ViewPage = 4,
            HomePage = 8
        }

        private static void Main()
        {

            // 4.
            // Set a new enum in three statements.
            RenderType type2 = RenderType.ViewPage;
            // 5.
            // See if the enum contains this flag.
            if ((type2 & RenderType.ViewPage) == RenderType.ViewPage)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ViewPage");
            }

            if ((type2 & RenderType.DataUri) == RenderType.DataUri)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DataUri");
            }
            if ((type2 & RenderType.GZip) == RenderType.GZip)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("GZip");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Whenever I run this code, it gives me an output of:

ViewPage
DataUri

I want output of just ViewPage as I am giving the value to my enum ViewPage.

Can anyone help me here?  Why is this? Is there anything wrong with my Enum declaration or code?

Comment: Small clarification: actually, there is **no** specific behavior of `[Flags]` in C# - it behaves exactly like any `enum` (or integer). The **BCL** has some `[Flags]` handling (for example, serialization), as do some IDE tools. But the *language*: doesn't care one iota about `[Flags]`.

Answer (score 4):

You have declared `DataUri = 0` so

```
(type2 & RenderType.DataUri) == RenderType.DataUri
```

will always evaluate to `true`.

Start your valid enum values at 1.

Answer (score 1):

Any number bitwise anded with zero is zero. Start the enum with one and increase by powers of two. Also, a better understanding of [binary numbers](http://www.math.grin.edu/~rebelsky/Courses/152/97F/Readings/student-binary) and [bitwise operators](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) will help

Answer (score 1):

DataUri is 0: so `x & DataUri` is always zero!
Try this:

```
if(type2 != RenderType.DataUri) {  
    if ((type2 & RenderType.ViewPage) == RenderType.ViewPage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ViewPage");
    }


    if ((type2 & RenderType.GZip) == RenderType.GZip)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GZip");
    }
}
```

When using Bitmasks the value 0 usually indicates a NONE-Flag. So you should start to count from 1 to 2^n, which is a better practise IMHO:

```
    [FlagsAttribute]
    private enum RenderType
    {
        None = 0,
        DataUri = 1,
        GZip = 2,
        ContentPage = 4,
        ViewPage = 8,
        HomePage = 16
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `x & 0` always equals zero.

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify 0 (zero) as a possible value for a [Flags] enum. Remember that a [Flags] enum is a bit field, and a value of zero doesn't really map into any of the fields, so it will always return true.

From the [Framework Design Guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2004/05/18/134208.aspx) by Krzysztof Cwalina:

> ```
> Avoid using flag enum values normal members that are negative or zero.
> ```
>
> Negative values produce unexpected/confusing results in bitwise operations. An enum value of zero creates problems with and operations, etc:

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `RenderType.DataUri` has the value `0`.

What your code does is to inspect the bitwise configuration of the `type2` enum variable by performing a bitwise `and` operation between `type2` and the enum member it's testing for.

In your example, `type2` has the value 4, which is `0100` in binary (up to the 4 bits that your enum requires). When you test for `RenderType.GZip` (`0001`), it does the following calculation:

```
0100 & 0001 = 0000
```

Since `0000 != 0001`, the `RenderType.GZip` bit is not set in `type2`. However, `0100 & 0000` is always `0000`, so you'll always get true when checking for `RenderType.DataUri`.

Essentially, a `Flags` enum uses a different bit for each of its members, but since `0` doesn't represent a bit in an integer, it won't behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you should start Flags enums at 1 due to how binary arithmetics work. I just want to add that you may want to use the HasFlag method (I believe new in .NET 4.0) to check the flags:

```
if(type2.HasFlag(RenderType.ViewPage))
{
   ...
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx